# Filter number of rows HTML table, splice array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, drop-down-menu

I have the following code which populates my table:

```
if (jsonObj[0].array !== 'undefined' && jsonObj[0].array.length > 0) {
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj[0].array.length; i++) {
    var table_row = "<tr><td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].siteId + "</td>";

    var date = new Date(0); 
    date.setUTCSeconds(jsonObj[0].array[i].time);
    table_row = table_row + "<td>" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "</td>";
    table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field1 + "</td>";
    table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field2 + "</td>";
    table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field3 + "</td>";
    table_row = table_row + "<td>" + jsonObj[0].array[i].field4 + "</td>";

    var totalCount = jsonObj[0].array[i].field1 + jsonObj[0].array[i].field2 + jsonObj[0].array[i].field3 + + jsonObj[0].array[i].field4;

    if (totalCount > 100) {
        table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
    } else if (totalCount > 80){
        table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
    } else {
        table_row = table_row + totalCount + "</td></tr>";
    }

    $("#my-table").find("#my-table-body").append(table_row);
}
```

}

I want to filter the table by only showing 10 rows - which is called from a drop down value:

```
document.getElementById=("#rowNumberSelection").onchange = function() {
    var rowNumber = document.getElementById("rowNumberSelection").value();

    if (rowNumber == "10") {
       /////
    }
```

}

I'm not sure how to slice the array at this point / only show that number of rows, can anyone help?

Comment: replace "var i = 0" with "var i = rowNumberSelection.value" to start after the first row

Comment: I have question regarding your original code. I am trying to understand what `jsonObj[0].array` does. Especially `.array`. I have a piece of code which I found and I am trying to understand it. It contains a similar structure. See here `data.findIndex(x => x.array==String('arr_id_'+t_id))`. I am interested in `x.array` what it does

Answer (score 0):

This will show just the first 10 rows of the table:

```
$("#my-table tr:lt(11)").show();
$("#my-table tr:gt(10)").hide();
```